# Sorting image coordinates in python

Tags: python

I want to sort four co-ordinates, for example- (180,120),(100,40),(100,120),(180,40). This co-ordinates will be returned in random order by the code. I want to sort these co-ordinates such that I have tuple in the following order - ((100,40),(100,120),(180,40),(180,120)). How I can achieve this in python?

One more set of co-ordinates are (170,118),(90,44),(80,120),(165,39)

[image]

Comment: `sorted([(180,120),(100,40),(100,120),(180,40)])` -> `[(100, 40), (100, 120), (180, 40), (180, 120)]`

Comment: Thanks mozway it worked.

Comment: Noticed one issue with Sorted method. If my input is  sorted([(179,120),(100,40),(100,120),(180,40)]) then result is [(100, 40), (100, 120), (179, 120), (180, 40)]. Any idea what can be done to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just sort based on X axis, then Y axis if X axes are equal,

Maybe something like this?:

```py
Points = [(180,120),(100,40),(100,120),(180,40)];

def Swap(Array, Index1, Index2):
    Temp = Array[Index1];
    Array[Index1] = Array[Index2];
    Array[Index2] = Temp;

def Sort(Array):
    for x in range(0, len(Array) - 1):
        if (Array[x][0] > Array[x+1][0]):
            Swap(Array, x, x+1);
        elif (Array[x][0] == Array[x+1][0]):
            if (Array[x][1] > Array[x+1][1]):
                Swap(Array, x, x+1);
```

Aight I did not know you could just call sorted() as shown by mozway, that is very convenient

Comment: Sorted method worked. Thanks for the function though.